# iOS Swift5 how can I check if an object is of type declared in array of types [Class.Type]?

Tags: error-handling, casting, type-conversion, swift5

I'm experimenting with error handling and am interested in what I can do with an array of class types.

**Is there a way for me to check if an object is of type declared in the array of [Class.Type] ?**

The "is" operator refuses to work with the type extracted from an array. How can I check if an object can be cast to that type or is an instance of that type?

```
class FooError: NSError { ... }

class BarError: NSError { ... }

protocol ErrorHandling {
    var types: [NSError.Type] { get }
    func handle(error: NSError)
}

class ErrorHandler: ErrorHandling {

    var types = [FooError.self, BarError.self]

    func handle(error: NSError) {

        for errorType in types {
            if error is errorType {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Swift operator for this is `is` see example below

```
if object is Class.Type {
    // object is of type Class.Type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to use equality and type(of:) function

```
public func handle(error: NSError) {
    for errorType in types {
        if type(of: error) == errorType {
            print("Handling: \(error), \(errorType)")
            return
        }
    }

    print("Could not handle: \(error))")
}

let api = ErrorHandler()

api.handle(error: FooError())
api.handle(error: BarError())
api.handle(error: NSError(domain: "test", code: 0, userInfo: nil))


Handling: Error Domain=test Code=0 "(null)", FooError
Handling: Error Domain=test Code=0 "(null)", BarError
Could not handle: Error Domain=test Code=0 "(null)")
```

Comment: You could write that check as `if types.contains(where: { $0 == type(of: error)}) {`